# ItemTouchHelper onSwiped() doesn't update data from constructor

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have created a class to handle swipe events:

```
public class CardViewSwipeListener : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
{
   private Context context;
   private List<Person> listWithData;
   private const int RESET_ADAPTER = 1;

    public CardViewSwipeListener(Context context, List<Person> listWithData)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listWithData = listWithData;
    }

    public override int GetMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.Start | ItemTouchHelper.End;
        return MakeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
    }

    public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
    {
        return true;
    }   

    public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
    {
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.End)
        {
            ((Activity)context).StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", listWithData[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].PhoneNumber))),RESET_ADAPTER);
            Toast.MakeText(context,"Call "+listWithData[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].Name,ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.Start)
        {
            ((Activity)context).StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("sms:{0}", this.listWithData[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].PhoneNumber))),RESET_ADAPTER;
            Toast.MakeText(context, "SMS " + this.listWithData[viewHolder.AdapterPosition].Name, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

In MainActivivty onCreate I use the following code to provide the recycler view to handle swipe events.

```
        itemTouchHelper   = new ItemTouchHelper(new CardViewSwipeListener(this, listWithData));

        recycler = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recycler);
        recycler.HasFixedSize = true;
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler.SetAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(listWithData,this));
        itemTouchHelper.AttachToRecyclerView(recycler);
```

The problem is that I need to change listWithData to another one, but when I do that onSwipe doesn't consider any changes.

Have no result:

```
itemTouchHelper   = new ItemTouchHelper(new CardViewSwipeListener(this, NewList));
        recycler.SetAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(NewList,this));
        itemTouchHelper.AttachToRecyclerView(recycler);
```

Java code solutions are also accepted)

Comment: is GetView called when you set new adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that i need to change listWithData to another one, but when i do that onSwipe doesn't consider any changes.

You could write a `Interface` to listen for a dismissal event from a `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` :

```
public interface IItemHelper
{
    //Called when an item has been dismissed by a swipe.
    void onItemDismiss(int position);
}
```

Implement `IItemHelper` interface in your `RecyclerViewAdapter` class :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter,IItemHelper
{
    List<string> items;

    ...

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<string> data)
    {
        items = data;
    }

    ...

    //Called when an item has been dismissed by a swipe.
    public void onItemDismiss(int position)
    {
        items.RemoveAt(position);
        NotifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

When you swip a Item, tell the adapter to dismiss this item:

```
public class CardViewSwipeListener : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
{ 
     ...

     public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
    {
        if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.End)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.Start)
        {
            ...
        }
        recyclerViewAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
    }
}
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bcdf.gif).

Comment: Shen today a have a day off, I will try your solution tomorrow, thx in advance

Comment: @Dmitry Ushkevich, is there any problem?

Comment: Sure, it saved me much time

Comment: @Dmitry Ushkevich, happy coding. : )

Comment: I'm running into this now but I don't understand how refreshing the data in the adapter updates the items in `onSwiped`?